# iPhone to retrieve gmail account details in app from setting

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, xcode4.2

I am making an application where I want to send an email using smtp server.

It's working fine but if user does not provide the correct gmail account details such as (email id and password) email is not send.

What I want to do is I want to access user gmail account details from setting tab of the iPhone into my app?

Is it possible to do retrieve the gmail account detail into the app?

Please help me out with this.

Following is my code:

```
-(IBAction)sendemail
{
    SKPSMTPMessage *testMsg = [[SKPSMTPMessage alloc] init];
    //testMsg.fromEmail = @"Lexi mobile";//nimit51parekh@gmail.com
    testMsg.fromEmail = soundOn;
    NSLog(@"str_Uname=%@",testMsg.fromEmail);
    //str_info = [str_info stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
    testMsg.toEmail = [string_emailinfo objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"autoemail=%@",testMsg.toEmail);
    testMsg.relayHost = @"smtp.gmail.com";
    testMsg.requiresAuth = YES;
    testMsg.login = soundOn;
    NSLog(@"autoelogin=%@",testMsg.login);
    testMsg.pass = vibrateOn;
    NSLog(@"autopass=%@",testMsg.pass);
    testMsg.subject = @"Photo Sharing";
    testMsg.wantsSecure = YES; 

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/umix-radio/id467041430?mt=8"];
    NSString *msg2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><b><a href=\"%@\">DOWNLOAD NOW</a></b>&nbsp&nbsp<a href=\"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/umix-radio/id467041430?mt=8\"></a></html>",url];
    NSString *sendmsg=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",msg2];
    NSLog(@"automsg=%@",sendmsg);

    testMsg.delegate = self;

    NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/plain",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                                                            sendmsg,kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"8bit",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];

    testMsg.parts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:plainPart,nil];
    [testMsg send];

    // [self DeleteRowAfterSending];
    //[self performSelector:@selector(DeleteRowAfterSending) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
}

-(void)messageSent:(SKPSMTPMessage *)message
{
    [message release];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Your email is sent successfully" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

    NSLog(@"delegate - message sent");
}

-(void)messageFailed:(SKPSMTPMessage *)message error:(NSError *)error
{
    [message release];

    // open an alert with just an OK button
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Fail" message:@"Message sending failure" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

    NSLog(@"delegate - error(%d): %@", [error code], [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What i want to do is i want to access user gamil account details from
>   setting tab of the iPhone into my app? is it possible to do retrive
>   the gamil account detail into the app?

No, and with good reason: *that functionality would allow any developer access to anyone's e-mail account*.

That would be a **massive** security hole.

Much like it is with Location Services, you're just going to have to ask the user to enter their e-mail address and password. And hope they want to trust your app with that kind of personal information. (Assuming Apple approves your app at all.)

Answer (score 1):

Let the user give your app authorization from Google. check the oauth autorization with google api at their developers site? 
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

As usual the user signs in with his account through google api and returns back to you an access_token to get information back from his account including his email which you need.